# Program 'ng' failed to run

Tags: angular, npm, windows-10, angular-cli

I am not able to run angular cli commands. When I type:

`ng`

I get error:

```
Program 'ng' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ ng
+ ~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng
+ ~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I tried uninstalling and installing it again:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
removed 269 packages in 2.209s
```

```
npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache):
Content verified: 4035 (209610714 bytes)
Index entries: 6536
Finished in 4.679s
```

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
C:\Users\U\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\U\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

@angular/cli@10.0.1 postinstall C:\Users\U\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@10.0.1
added 259 packages from 201 contributors and updated 10 packages in 11.611s
```

After uninstall files are removed from `C:\Users\U\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular` and after installation they are there again. I see file `C:\Users\U\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng` but above error message appear when I try to run it.

I tried installing different versions but nothing seems to work.

I also tried setting ExecutionPolicy that I've seen in this [blog](https://thecodebuzz.com/program-ng-failed-to-run-no-application-is-associated/): but it is still not working.

Comment: Bit of a weird one, have you tried closing your terminal after install and launching a new one?

Comment: Yes, I have. I also tried restarting my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `C:\Users\U\AppData\Roaming\npm` to System Variable Path has worked for me. After that I have restarted my console.